# Check if a certain value already exist

Tags: javascript, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.4.18, I'm trying to check if a certain value in a specific column already exists;
example of the table:

| Name | Money | Weapons | Skin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | first_value | first_value | first_value |
| Second | second_value | second_value | second_value |

I would like to check if the value "First" in the column "Name" already exists, if true do nothing else creates the values.

I'm using as documentation [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if/)

```
IF NOT (SELECT * FROM players WHERE Name = '${player.name}')
THEN
INSERT INTO players (Name, Money, Weapons, Skin) VALUES ('${player.name}',100,'weapon_pistol,weapon_pistol_mk2', 'player_zero')
END IF;
```

The error is:

```
(node:10596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: (conn=212, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF'
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May you share the JavaScript code too?

Comment: First of all, you should not create queries with string templates but use parameterized queries. Second, this code may lead to racecoditions, and thus probably to inconsistencies in your data. If you want your `name` column to be unique, you should create a `UNIQUE` constraint and handle errors originating from that contraint appropriately ...

Comment: try this
    INSERT INTO players (Name, Money, Weapons, Skin)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'yourName', 'yourMony', 'yourSkin') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT name FROM players WHERE name = 'yourName'
    ) LIMIT 1;